# UnsatisfiedDependencyException when trying to connect with Quartz DataSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, quartz-scheduler

I am currently using Quartz to store scheduled jobs. While trying to use jobstore of type jdbc to persist scheduled jobs in secondary quartz database I am getting bunch of errors regarding injections, beans.

> Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in pl.certificatemanager.CertificateManagerApp.repository.UserRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#29fa6b65' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#29fa6b65': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration$JdbcStoreTypeConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type

**Error regarding my repository and @EnableJpaRepositories**

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in pl.certificatemanager.CertificateManagerApp.repository.UserRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#29fa6b65' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#29fa6b65': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration$JdbcStoreTypeConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type

**Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument**

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#29fa6b65': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration$JdbcStoreTypeConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type

**And last one concerning Quartz DataSource directly. However I think resolving problems with primary DataSource first is priority for now.**

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration$JdbcStoreTypeConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type

**application.properties**

```
## Primary DataSource properties
database1.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/certificatemanagerdb
database1.datasource.username=root
database1.datasource.password=root
database1.datasource.configuration.maximum-pool-size=30
database1.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

## Quartz properties
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
database2.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz_schema
database2.datasource.username=root
database2.datasource.password=root
database2.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**DataSourcesConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DataSourcesConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("database1.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("database1.datasource.first.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource firstDataSource(DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties) {
        return firstDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @QuartzDataSource
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database2.datasource")
    public DataSource quartzDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig it injects jwtFilter mentioned in error**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomPasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(customPasswordEncoder.getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http = http.csrf().disable().cors().disable();

        http = http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and();

        http = http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, exception) -> {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, exception.getMessage());
                }).and();

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**userRepo**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findUserById(Long id);
    User findByUsername(String username);
    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
}
```

When commenting out method **quartzDataSource()** in **DataSourcesConfiguration** everything works fine (ignoring persisting data of Quartz Scheduler), so I suspect something with configuring Quartz DataSource intervene with my whole app.

Injected class **JwtUtil** in **SecurityConfig** is annotated with @Component.

Comment: database will be configured with `spring.datasource` as prefix for the configuration parameter, not `databasex.datasource`

Comment: Could you be more precise @Jens on how to distinguish typing of  two data sources in application.properties? When deleting Bean related to creating Quartz DataSource, Application runs fine and connects with my primary database.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Replaced `spring.datasource.url=` with `spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=` and everything works fine.

Comment: You solved your problem by replacing a property which is not in your configuration?

Comment: It clearly was in my configuration, but with prefix `database2.datasource.url=`. So according to my past configuration the resolved issue would look like this `database2.datasource.jdbcUrl=`. However I decided to write down my previous answer with the most neutral way, that most people will recognize right away. According to Spring documentation you are permitted to use custom datasource name properties [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-data-access.html).